# C# ReceiveAsync response corrupt

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, response

Adding random data into response. This happens on all sites and pages, and for each particular page these data is fixed.
Example:

```
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.11

1fb4
<!DOCTYPE html..........
```

or

```
<script>
    $('#toggle_debug').cl
134
ick(function () {
```

Сode:

```
if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
{
    Response.AddRange(e.Buffer);
    if (Response.Count >= MaxContentLength)
    {
        Final();
    }
    else
    {
        e.SetBuffer(0, BufferSize);
        e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(e);
    }
}
```

Response - List with bytes. Also, StringBuilder and other have same problem. Additional symbols is fixed, not change. What could be wrong?

Comment: `Receive` and `Read` return an integer that tells you how many bytes were read. Only that many bytes in the buffer are valid. You need to use a loop if you want to read everything.

Comment: No need to add the entire buffer, and part of it?

Comment: I guess you need to use the first `e.BytesTransferred` bytes of the buffer. Read the docs for details. Something like `Response.AddRange(e.Buffer.Take(e.BytesTransferred))`

Comment: @CodesInChaos Question is about `ReceiveAsync` not `Receive` or `Read`, no?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I didn't work with `ReceiveAsync` yet, but I expect it to share that characteristic with `Read`&co. Some details, like return value vs. `e.BytesTransferred` change, but I expect the basic issue of getting less bytes than requested to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
Response.AddRange(new ArraySegment<byte>(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred));
```

Comment: maybe, you mean it

    Response.AddRange(new ArraySegment<byte>(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred).Array);

Not working :с